# Plotly geoplot working in IE but not Chrome or Firefox

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to create a geo-Plot using the great plotly library with R. The following minimal example works with IE (11.0.9600.18524), but not Chrome (51.0.2704.106) and Firefox (ESR 45.5.1). The legend is shown, but no map appears.

Minimal Example

```
data <- data.frame(countryCode = c("DEU", "CHE"), measure = c(10, 20))

p <- plot_geo(data) %>%
         add_trace(
         z = ~measure, color = ~measure, locations = ~countryCode
         )
p
```

All browsers do not have access to the internet. Checking Chrome's log an error message:

https://cdn.plot.ly/world_110m.json Failed to load resource:

```
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
plotly-latest.min.js:51 Uncaught (in promise) Error: unexpected error while fetching topojson file at https://cdn.plot.ly/world_110m.json(…)
plotly-latest.min.js:51 Uncaught (in promise) Error: unexpected error while fetching topojson file at https://cdn.plot.ly/world_110m.json(…)
```

Any ideas how to run these kind of plots in Chrome and Firefox offline?

Edit: Using plotly 4.5.6 on Windows 7

Comment: it works for me on Chrome. plotly_4.5.6  and I am using a Mac

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your d3r package to the newest version. I had a similar issue with another d3.js package. It is trying to fetch the necessary javascrip packages online instead of using the offline version in d3r. The newest update to d3r fixed this issue to make offline be the default.

Comment: I just installed d3r 0.6, unfortunately this did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not a proper solution, but perhaps the information helps...

I tried plotting your code in RStudio with internet connection, and then opening it in IE, Firefox and Chrome, all worked well.

The same scenario without internet did neither work at RStudio nor at any web-browsers. In your case, IE must be rendering the cache in stead of fetching the "topojson" from cdn.plot.ly.

As per the plot.ly R doc at https://plot.ly/r/offline/,

> Plotly R figures appear interactively within RStudio's graphics viewer without any calls to Plotly's server by default.

However, the world-map seems to be fetched from the CDN, and hence you need internet connection.

**Workaround:**
Use the option from the RStudio Viewer >  Save as Web Page... and then you can use the html file in any browser w/o internet.